# python - fit two time series files

Tags: python, time-series

I am still pretty new to python so please be indulgent with me.

I have two dataframes, one contains temperature data that is recorded in 2 sec-intervals (due to measurement difficulties, the files ar sometimes in even and sometimes in uneven seconds), the other one is recorded in 2.5 min-intervals. 
My first problem is: the 2 sec-interval-file only contains the timesteps in the file name, not in the file contents. Means: the first file is called "temp_20151103_013042", containing date and time. Inside the file there is only one temperature value and nothing else. I have 20,000 files (so I have 20,000 temperature values, recorded in around 15 hours).
The second one is just one file (as it is common) looking like this:

```
YYYY MM DD HH MM SS station1
2015 11 03 01 30 30 3.46
2015 11 03 01 32 00 4.21
...
```

, it contains around 1,000 rows with around 1,000 temperature values.

I now want to do time series analyses with these files, like correlations etc. Can anybody help me with the problem with the first file? I dont even know how to start :( I somehow need to "kick out" the files I dont need and to get a 2.5 min-interval for both files. Any help would be so much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `pandas` for this but this question is a bit broad, you need to list all the files, parse the time stamp from the filename and concatenate all the dfs and resample

Comment: thank you for you answer! probably it is too much but could you help me showing you approach with code? how do i parse the time stamp from the file name e.g.? your approach sounds good to me but i have no idea how to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a Pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) this is the kind of question it was made for.

If you are not sure how to install it, you can consider miniconda. This is a binary distribution, relieving you from the burden of compiling some of the dependencies